# Remove certain commits in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

can you advice how I can revert to earlier good commit. Below is my commit code

```
git log --oneline
```

```
as4c704 (HEAD -> mybranch, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'branchA' of repo_name into master
e325c09 (origin/branchA) message
4549e4c Merge branch 'branchB' of repo_name into master
2f32d73 (origin/branchB) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into branchB
221e689 Merge branch 'branchC' of repo name into master
f33c1c (origin/branchC) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into branchC
6782c19 Merge branch 'branchD' of repo_name into master
1d3s525 Merge branch 'branchE' of repo_name into master
16438a DbranchE
112a682 message
dd3d883 BranchF message
5122492 BranchF message
bg3e17 message
33f71c message
346d27 message
... more
```

How can i keep commit 346d27, 33f71c  and 221e689  and rest remove it from 33f71c   onwards

Comment: Look into interactive rebase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+old+commits

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue the command `git rebase -i 33f71c` and edit each commit you want to remove entering the `drop` command.

Then save, exit, and issue the command `git push --force`.

Comment: why u rebase this 33f71c  hash. as this i want to keep it

Comment: WIth rebase you have to pass the hash of the commit previous to the you need to edit.